# JavaFX: Exception on thread is not logged to System output

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea, javafx

In my JavaFX 8 app, I have a thread that runs a loop and occasionally updates the UI. Somewhere in this thread, there's an exception causing me grief. Finding it wouldn't be a problem, except exceptions on worker threads don't seem to be logged to `System` output the same as those on the main program thread.

What I mean is, when I run the program, if something breaks in `main()`, IntelliJ prints the exception message and a stack trace to the Run view (standard out, AFAIC). On the other hand, if something breaks in my thread, I don't get the same verbose output. In fact, most of the time, I don't get anything at all - just a mysteriously non-functioning program.

Is there another step I need to take to capture errors in worker threads? Is my environment misconfigured? This makes debugging next to impossible - any help appreciated!

Comment: Could you post the code and stacktrace error here?

Comment: Depending on your threading model exceptions are not propagated to the main thread, they just kill the thread they are thrown from. You might benifit from adding a try/catch to your "run" method when starting the thread.

Comment: @SamuelÅslund You are correct. I tried adding a try/catch to the thread task and started seeing exceptions. With some more searching I found that this is the default behavior for certain Runnables. I'm not clear on why it works this way, but at least now I can continue to debug. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I guess your answer/comment means I should turn my comment into an answer.)

Depending on your threading model exceptions are not propagated to the main thread, they just kill the thread they are thrown from. You might benefit from adding a try/catch to your "run" method when starting the thread.

Answer (score 2):

Between Samuel's comment and some searching, I've got my answer; Runnables tend to consume their errors, so they're never thrown up to the main thread. This means that with no error handling, they simply disappear and the thread is broken.

The solution in my case is to add try/catch blocks in my task. This is dumping errors the way I expect now.

Comment: I'll accept this as an answer and close this question in 2 days.